# Renaming and moving file using crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I want to make a backup of my history.txt file, where I store some information of my system. I would like to do this using the crontab and this is what I have now in my crontab:

```
0 * * * * cp -a history.txt "history-$(date + "%Y%m%d-%h%m%s")" ; mv "history-$(date + "%Y%m%d-%h%m%s")" l-systems
```

Like you can see i want to preform the backup every hour and I want to give the file a name with the date. First I make a cp of the file and rename it. After that I try to move the new file in a directory called l-systems. This doesn't work right now, can someone help?

Comment: You need to escape % like `\%Y`, otherwise cron will convert % to newline.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to make a backup shell script like so:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

DATE=$(date + "%Y%m%d-%h%m%s")
cp -a history.txt "history-$DATE"
mv "history-$DATE" l-systems
```

The call this script from crontab. Since we use the same variable twice it will always be the same for both commands regardless of how long each takes

Comment: Right now I have an .sh file called backup.sh to make backups from my history.txt file. The backup.sh file has the code you put in your comment. In my crontab I have "  * * * * * /home/matias/Documents/project/l-system/backup.sh  " Normally this would run the file backup.sh file every minute but it is still not working?

Comment: You should make sure the file has 755(rwxr-xr-x) permissions.